# Scraping different date formats with one line of RegEx

Tags: html, regex, web-scraping

I'm busy scraping this page on [airwars.org](https://airwars.org/coalition-civcas-2017-sept/) with Outwit hub and it's a mess.

I would like to scrape all the dates but they're formatted differently:

- September 4th 2017
- September 5th – 6th 2017
- September 6th-7th 2017
- September 8th/9th 2017

The first one is `September \d+[a-z]+ 2017` but how do I target them all in one line of RegEx?

Comment: I can't say this definitively since I rarely write original regex expressions, but I think you need to do some string parsing with a programming language to solve this. For example, 8th/9th is two different days. I think you will need to split this up into separate instances of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only want to match September and those dates, then you could use a pattern like this:

```
September \d+th.*?2017
```

However, if you want to match all the months, then you can use

```
(?:January|...|December) \d+th.*?2017
```

Keep in mind that using `.*?` will match strings like `September 4th something in 2017`, depending on your source data the pattern might be wrong.

So, for the specific data format you posted you can use this other pattern:

```
September \d+th(?:\s?[–\/-]\s?\d+th)?\s*2017
```